# rotation field has period orbit

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, rotations, plane-curves

Given $\varphi$ a periodic orbit of $X=(X_1,X_2)$, $C^1$ in $\Delta\subset \mathbb{R^2}$. If
$X_\theta=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta  
\end{array}
\right] \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
X_1  \\
X_2  
\end{array}
\right]$, prove that:

$a)$ Prove that exists $\delta>0$,  $|\theta|<\delta$, that $X_\theta$ has a periodic orbit $\varphi_\theta$, which $\varphi_\theta \to \varphi$ when $\theta \to 0$.
$b)$ Prove that $\varphi_\theta$ are all disjoint and $$\bigcup_{|\theta|\leq \delta}\varphi_\theta$$ is an annular region.

So, $a)$ is ok because if $\theta\in (0,1/n)$ and, if $n\to \infty$ then $\theta\to 0$. $X_\theta$ is linear and cos, sin is continuous, then $X_\theta \to X_0$, hence $\varphi_\theta \to \varphi_0$.
For the second, i tried considered poincaré maps and see their graphics (everything makes me concluded that is an annular region, geometrically), how can i write this argument?

edit: I don't know how write the annular region yet... someone can help me?

Comment: I cannot understand your setup; is $X$ a given dynamical system that has a periodic orbit and now you are looking at the rotated dynamical system?

Comment: Yes. Considering $\theta$, i need to prove that exists a distance of $\theta=0$ that the others $X_\theta$ has also a periodic orbit.

Comment: i edited. is it better to understand?

Comment: I still don't think I understand the setting, what are the dynamics of $X_\theta$ exactly? There is a trivial reading of the situation that if you apply an injective function to a periodic orbit then you get a periodic orbit with the same period, but I don't think that's what you intend to do here.

Comment: $X_\theta$ has periodic orbits because its just a rotation. I want to prove that, considering a convenient $\varphi_\theta$ "sequence" (because its in $\theta$) we need that $\varphi_\theta \to \varphi$

Comment: Again, I think this is either really trivial or else I'm not understanding it, because if you're just applying a rotation to the original periodic orbit of $X$, then trivially $\varphi_\theta \to \varphi$ as $\theta \to 0$ since the rotation matrix itself goes to $I$ as $\theta \to 0$.

Comment: ok.. i got it. I think that i didnt understood the problem before. Its really very simple.